# Passing text from textarea through ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to grab text from a textarea on my form and pass it through ajax into my database. For some reason it is just giving me an empty result for "coverletter"

my code is

```
 <textarea id="elm1" required></textarea>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#apply").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                     var coverletter = $("#elm1").val();
             var oppid = "1";
             var networkid = "10294";

                    $.ajax({
                            url: "/opportunity/apply",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: {coverletter:coverletter, oppid:oppid, networkid:networkid},
                            success: function(data) {
                                 $("#thecontent").html(data);

                            },
                            error: function() {
                                    alert("Please enter valid email id!");
                            }
                    });
            });




    if($("#elm1").length > 0){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea#elm1",
            theme: "modern",
            height:200,
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink link pagebreak spellchecker",
                "wordcount nonbreaking",

            ],
                             menubar: "",
            toolbar: "bold italic underline|",

        });
    }
});
```

the POST response from firebug inspect is : 
`coverletter` 
`networkid  10294`
`oppid  1`

`Source`
`coverletter=&oppid=1&networkid=10294`

I even added `alert (coverletter);`

it just gives an empty alert window.

Comment: By "response" do you mean the response you get back from the server?  What are you expecting to get back from the server?  Why?  Where is the server-side code?

Comment: this i mean i get from when i insepect with firebug. the server just inputs nothing into the coverletter field in my db

Comment: var coverletter = $("#coverletter").val(); you dont have an element with the id of coverletter

Comment: `$("#coverletter")` is looking for `id="coverletter"` not `name="coverletter"`. Did you try accessing the textarea with it's id elm1?

Comment: I did indeed, that just gives empty value as well.

Comment: I don't know anything about tinymce but you may be typing into an injected element rather than the textarea. Can you save a reference when you init tinymce and use tinymce.Editor.getContent() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
var coverletter = tinymce.get('elm1').getContent();
```

or

```
var coverletter = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```